# Basic Texts on Mantra Shastra

Tags: mantras, resource

I am looking for some texts that could teach the basics of Mantra Shastra. I am specially interested in their reasoning, pronunciation and historical context. Kindly recommend texts of the same kind.

Comment: Are you looking for text in specific language like English Hindi or Sanskrit?

Comment: English or Hindi will be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To learn about Mantra Shastra, One can read **Sri Vidyarnava Tantra**. It deals with mantra and vidhya in great depth. The text also covers yantram for each mahavidya and explain in detail. I found **Hindi version of the book in 2 parts**.

Link to the books:

[**Sri Vidyarnava Tantra, (Author: Kapildev Narayana) Part 1.**](https://archive.org/details/SriVidyarnavaTantraPurvardhaPartOneKapildevNarayana/page/n41/mode/2up)
[**Sri Vidyarnava Tantra, (Author: Kapildev Narayana) Part 2.**](https://archive.org/details/SriVidyarnavaTantraUttarardhaPartIISriKapildevNarayana/page/n3/mode/2up)

Garland of letters by by Arthur Avalon is another option which directly deals with Mantra only.
[**The_Garland_of_Letters-_By_Arthur_Avalon**](http://www.mysticknowledge.org/The_Garland_of_Letters-_By_Arthur_Avalon.pdf)

Comment: Give some upadesha to me via chat :P

Comment: @hanugm I don't know any upadesha lol

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to many popular books which explain them. But if you are looking for the original mantra shashtra, you can read Lakshmi Tantra.

Comment: Thank you. Is it accepted as a foundation for the subject, and have you read it?

Comment: Also, can you site any other popular sources?

Comment: Popular sources - there are a few like Om Swami - but he won't give you mantras directly other than some. His book on mantra science is a good book on it. Some western authors - Thomas Ashley Ferrand (although he seems to be trained in India by proper guru-shishya tradition) is one popular author on this topic and he actually details various mantras which you can start practicing immediately and some people say that they have got positive results from it. Lakshmi Tantra is the original hindu scripture. It is available online.

Comment: Maybe a portion of that be contained in Narshima Lakshmi Stotram @Aditya Singh?